# PHP query to sql server syntax, all i have is the ASP.NET connection string

Tags: php, asp.net, sql-server, syntax

I've got a project on my hands.

In our new hour-registration software, we want to make a query to a database that is located at an external company.

The external company has opened a connection that we've used for another application in ASP.NET.

I want to make a query from the hour-registration PHP project to this database, but I can't make the connection syntax work.

All I have at this moment is the ASP.NET connection string.
(the database is SQL server)

ASP.NET connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="NAV_ODS_2016ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=AX1234SQL;Initial Catalog=NAV_ODS_2016;User ID=test;Password=test" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="NAV_ODS_2016ConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=AX1234SQL;Initial Catalog=NAV_ODS_2016;User ID=test" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="NAV2016Test" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Nav.csdl|res://*/Nav.ssdl|res://*/Nav.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=AX1234SQL;initial catalog=NAV_ODS_2016;persist security info=True;user id=test;password=test;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Any ideas how to do this, I've tried the official PHP user manual.

Comment: I hope the external company has a good firewall configuration and/or vpn and has not opened port 1433 to the rest of the world.

Comment: what php database api are you going to use? PDO or mysqli?

Comment: @RamRaider mysqli is for mysql databases, he is trying to connect to MS SqlServer.

Comment: good point - just seeing if anyone was paying attention - i clearly wasn't!

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but I will be using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Typed in this textbox here so...

```
$config = new DOMDocument();
$config->loadXML('path/to/web.config');

$connection = [];

foreach($config->selectNodes('//connectionStrings/add[@providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"]') as $element)
{
    $connectionString = $element->getAttribute('connectionString');
    $key = $element->getAttribute('name');
    $parts = explode(';', $connectionString);
    $cnData = [];
    foreach($parts as $part)
    {
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $part);
        $cnData[$key] = $value;
    }
    // add error checking, seriously...
    $hostname = $cnData['Data Source'];
    $username = $cnData['User Id'];
    $database = $cnData['Initial Catalog'];
    $password = $cnData['Password'] ?: null;
    $port = $cnData['Port'] ?: 1433;

    $connection[$name] = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server={$hostname};Database={$database}; Uid={$username};Pwd={$password}");
}
```

You should end up with:

`$connection['NAV_ODS_2016ConnectionString']` and `$connection['NAV_ODS_2016ConnectionString1']`

that you can use to communicate with the database.

Comment: I'm not so good at this, dont know what to fill in where.
And this path: $config->loadXML('path/to/web.config'); 
Should I have a document here?
Could you please give me an example of how you would use this, and in a query?

Comment: those connectionStrings are in web.config form so I am assuming you probably either have the entire ASP.NET web.config file, or are able to save the snippet with the connectionStrings somewhere. that would be the path you need. once you have something like this up and running you can follow any PDO tutorial to execute queries and other statements